# Problem with play-services-measurement-base on ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, ionic3, ionic-native

I have a problem on an ionic project that it started happening yesterday without modifying any dependency.

When I run `ionic cordova run android` I have this error:

```
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.5.0,16.5.0], [16.4.0,16.4.0]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

But I didn't installed any dependency in these days.

This is my `cordova plugins` list:

```
cordova-fabric-plugin 1.1.14-dev "cordova-fabric-plugin"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.0.9 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-appminimize 1.0.1 "AppMinimize"
cordova-plugin-apprate 1.4.0 "AppRate"
cordova-plugin-appsee 2.6.0 "Appsee"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 3.2.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-freshchat 1.2.0 "Freshchat plugin for Phonegap"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-inapppurchase-fixed 1.1.0 "In App Purchase"
cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.2.2 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.3.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.4 "SocialSharing"
cordova-support-google-services 1.2.1 "cordova-support-google-services"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-deeplinks 1.0.19 "Ionic Deeplink Plugin"
nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio 1.0.1 "background-audio"
pushwoosh-cordova-plugin 7.13.0 "Pushwoosh"
```

I found these dependencies in my `platforms/android/app/build.gradle` (if it's good to know):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support:design:27.+"
    compile "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.60"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:5.13.0"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-amazon:5.13.0"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-badge:5.13.0"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-inbox:5.13.0"
    compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-inbox-ui:5.13.0"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.38.1"
    compile "com.appsee:appsee-android:2.6.0"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

I don't know where to search. I found a workaround that is disabling version check of GoogleServicesPlugin in the `platforms/android/build.gradle` making: `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true` but it doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: It seems like i'm not the only one. [Here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-cordova-run-android-firebase-error-all-of-a-sudden/163204/8).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No solutions posted here worked for me. A wonderful person opened a [pull request](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/pull/1058) in the `cordova-firebase-plugin` official repo and it works.

Steps I did:

1 - Remove cordova-firebase-plugin with `ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase`

2 - Install: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex`

3 - `rm -rf node_modules/ plugins/ platforms/android package-lock.json`

4 - `ionic cordova platform add android && npm install`

And now it's working.

Comment: sir it got error after install above command :Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue via registry.

Comment: Does actually work for android. But i got an error when adding platform ios:

Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase': CordovaError: Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "xcode" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.

Comment: As of today (June 19) the owner of that PR has created his [own fork of the plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase) so the command to install it would be `ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase`

Comment: Superb it worked. Thanks a ton Man. God bless you :)

Answer (score 19):

I found a solution for me in the forum mentioned in Yannic Hamann answer  ([Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-cordova-run-android-firebase-error-all-of-a-sudden/163204/22)).

The comment from *systems_qualigy* [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-cordova-run-android-firebase-error-all-of-a-sudden/163204/30) is about locking the versions in project.properties.

```
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8 
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0 
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1 
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4
```

I need also to lock the version of

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8
```

I took the version from Martins answer and could succesfully rebuild my project.

Comment: it works thanks! the `project.properties` file can be found inside `platforms/android/` folder.

Comment: @HankLapidez : i got this error :> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8 .
  Searched in the following locations:

Comment: @Kapilsoni Try "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9" or search for a version already in your gradle cache

Comment: @HankLapidez:i got this error : error: cannot find symbol
public class FirebasePluginInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
                                                     ^

Comment: @Kapilsoni the [FirebaseInstanceIdService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService) had been deprecated... while it should still find that class.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: means sir we have put above link code inside the AndroidManifest.xml i am right?

Comment: @Kapilsoni these setting go into `platforms/android/project.properties`.

Comment: Applying this changes to `platforms/android/project.properties` fixed the problem in my project, but what about the warning at the top of this file? `#Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!` where are these values taken from and when will be overrided?

Answer (score 6):

We are now maintaining a forked version which includes all the changes & fixes done by different authors (who have saved everyone from this Google's move).

https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib#difference-from-the-fork-repository

So, now just remove the existing plugin with:

```sh
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase
```

And now, install new version with

```sh
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib --save
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hi , I am trying to install this but its stuck

Comment: Can you mention your `cordova-cli`, `cordova-android` & `cordova-ios` version?

Comment: I am not sure its releted I am seeing this issue now "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined, i am using ionic 1

Comment: @Rich5757 I am still on Ionic 1 as well....did you resolve this Firebase issue and the getToken issue.  I think the getToken is related because my problems all started at the same time and we made no plugin/dependency changes (for almost 3 months now).  So whatever google did to Firebase caused the getToken issue as well.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal - is this going to be a permanent fix for the future `cordova-plugin-firebase` or do I need to permanently append my upgrade scripts to use this new forked version of the plugin?

Comment: It depends. We are trying to maintain the fork as long as fixes & improvements are being done.

Answer (score 4):

The Problem was due to the recent updates in firebase where some methods are now deprecated, check out [Android Firebase releases](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android). To fix the problem use the following patch of cordova plugin :

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue
```

Answer (score 3):

do as it says and run `./gradlew :app:dependencies` in the Andoird project directory.

`support-v4` is even added three times:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+"
```

alike this the Gradle project synchronizes:

```
implementation project(":CordovaLib")

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8"

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"

implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3"

implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.60"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"
implementation "com.appsee:appsee-android:2.6.0"

implementation "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:5.13.0"
implementation "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-amazon:5.13.0"
implementation "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-badge:5.13.0"
implementation "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-inbox:5.13.0"
implementation "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh-inbox-ui:5.13.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

I am having exactly the same issue. The problem is caused by `cordova-plugin-firebase`. I am currently investigating. Will update this answer when I found the exact course.

For now you can try to `ionic cordova plugin rm <plugin>` to see whether this resolves your current error too.

**Update:**
Have a look [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-cordova-run-android-firebase-error-all-of-a-sudden/163204/22) for possible fixes. [This](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/pull/1058/commits/cfc261c32ca346f5c107b6a1b458299390d38d08) open PR seems to work. Hopefully it will be merged very soon.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same as you. I think the problem is the firebase plugin. I could try but, we use it for a/b tests so, I should make it works soon. Let me know if you solve this :)

Comment: Their travis tests are failing https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

Answer (score 2):

I just added below in project.properties which is under android platform dir and it got worked

```
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8 
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0 
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1 
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4
```

Comment: It worked for me too,I added above code gradle.build  and project.properties files

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error, I just deleted *platforms/android* and installed again (ionic cordova prepare android) then everything went back as it was.

Comment: it seems to make sense, previous builds conflict with the current plugin and its dependencies (probably), doing from scratch it will have to generate correctly according to the installed plugins. I'll test, thank you very much for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

**Ionic 4 : 20-05-2019**

This works for me:

*platforms/android/project.properties*

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-firebase/com1-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4
cordova.system.library.7=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to remove firebase using

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
```

and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow my perfect solution for the cordova firebase issue.

1. ionic cordova platform rm android
2. npm uninstall -g cordova
3. npm install -g cordova@9.0.0
4. ionic cordova platform add android (e.g v8.0.0)
5. ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex (e.g v6.0.7)
6. ionic cordova run android

New cordova-plugin-firebasex plugin will fix all the issues related to firebase and it is really good alternative for cordova-plugin-firebase.